How to link my JS file from a different directory to my EJS file
I have an ejs file in the following directory:
./admin/admin.ejs
and i have plain old JS file in the following directory:
./public/client.js
and an express app in the following directory:
./app.js
that renders the ejs file with the following code:
const express = require("express");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const { sessionMiddleware, wrap } = require("./server/sessionStore");
const { createServer } = require("node:http");
const { join } = require("node:path");

const app = express();
const server = createServer(app);

const db = require("./databases/dbChooser");
const config = require("./server/config");
const { banCheckMiddleware } = require("./server/middleware");

const io = new Server(server, config.cors);

const WorkerPool = require("./server/workerPool");
const workers = new WorkerPool(1, "./drawingWorker");

app.use(sessionMiddleware);
app.use(banCheckMiddleware);

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", join(__dirname, "./admin"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  if (!req.session.initialized) {
    req.session.initialized = true;
    req.session.visitCount = 1;
  } else {
    req.session.visitCount = (req.session.visitCount || 0) + 1;
  }
  res.sendFile(join(__dirname, "./public/index.html"));
});

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.static("admin"));

the ejs renders fine and everything works on surface level, but when i try using the client.js script in my EJS file i get the following error:
Refused to execute script from 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/public/client.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
My quick fix was to create a separate js file in the admin dir and copy and paste the client js code in it,and that works fine no errors. I also tried doing this:
   <script type = "text/javascript" src="../public/client.js"></script>
but that doesnt work.The JS and CSS files inside the admin dir work fine but its when i try to reference another file from a different dir is when it gets angry.

How did you link the script in the index.html file?

@GreenSaiko 

Try to write it as src="/client.js"

Please see the following examples which may help you to clarify the working of express.static middleware, as well as the relative references.
The following two statements will essentially make the two separate folders accessible from the same request URL.
app.use(express.static('admin'));
app.use(express.static('public'));

example:
Suppose the site has the following folders and files under it.
<site directory>
   public
      code1.js
   admin
      code2.js

Now, let us assume origin as http://localhost:3000
If so, the following two direct requests from a Browser are valid. Both these requests will display the source code of the respective files in the Browser.
1. http://localhost:3000/code1.js
2. http://localhost:3000/code2.js

On these basis, let us see the same when it is referenced from a file.
Let us assume the following site, the index.html is in public folder. The content of it is shown below.
<site directory>
   public
      index.html
      code1.js
   admin
      code2.js

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  Reference to JS
</head>
<body></body>
<script src="./code1.js"></script>
<script src="./code2.js"></script>

if so, the request URL http://localhost/index.html will load the same file - index.html successfully, and then execute the code in code1.js and code2.js respectively. It means the two references within it are valid and note that code2.js is from another folder admin.
Note :
Please note that once an EJS file renders, then it has become a plain
html file, and the JavaScript source files referenced in it will be executed in the Browser
just as it was in an ordinary html file. This was the reason I did not bring EJS file into the discussions and examples above.
